# jqGrid filter row is out of sync with grid columns

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Please look at my jsFiddle posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/chugh97/w3Kzt/1/

I have a fixed width jqGrid with scroll enabled and shrinktofit: false. Now when I tab through the 4th field in the jqGrid filter textbox, the filter textboxes are misalinged with the jqGrid columns. How can this be fixed?

Comment: About the second problem: which web browser you use for the tests? I tried the jsFiddle demo in Google Chrome and in IE9 and can't see any problem. The scroll position was not changed by filtering. One more general remark. The main goal of the stackoverflow is to *share the questions and answer with other users*. From the point of view it's better to make *separate question* instead of the usage of cumulative questions with many problems which you have. The cumulative questions could not be found so good by searching on the stackoverflow.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for your comments.I'll separate the questions out for the 2nd part, About part1 have you got any solution which might work?

Comment: jqGrid has very restricted support of keyboard navigation. I agree that the problem which you describe exist. To fix the problem one have to bind some key events or focus events and synchronize the scrolling manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jqGrid has very restricted support of keyboard navigation. I agree that the problem which you describe exist in the current (v. 4.3.1) implementation of jqGrid. So +1 from me for the question.

To fix the problem I suggest the following

```
$('#grid').closest('.ui-jqgrid-view')
    .find('.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar .ui-th-column')
    .find('input, select')
    .focus(function (e) {
        var $header = $(e.target).closest('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv'),
            $body = $header.siblings('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv');

        setTimeout(function () {
            // we syncronize the scroll in the separate thread
            // to be sure that the new scrolling value
            // already set in the grid header
            $body[0].scrollLeft =  $header[0].scrollLeft;
        }, 0);
    });
```

The usage of `setTimeout` is required in the Google Chrome web browser for example.

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SyncronizeScrollPosition.htm).

Comment: Excellent work!! I think you are a star!! Very much appreciated.